# 9patch image as CheckBox in android

Tags: android, xml, layout, nine-patch

I'm very new to 9patches and I still tries to figure out how it works. I try to make `CheckBox` with 9 patches but they not scale properly. So my XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_cases_checked" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_cases_default" android:state_checked="false"  />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_cases_default" />
</selector>
```

in draw9patch.bat 9path scales fine to me:
[image: Scaling 9patch in draw9patch.bat] 
but in prewiev it dosn't scale:

[image: Scaling in AS preview]

In layout code for `CheckBox` looks like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
                android:id="@+id/stepCheckBox1"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:button="@drawable/checkbox_cases" />
```

I really don't know why this image dont scale up for 48dp to 48dp. Some help would be appreciated :) Thanks!

Comment: try running your app. may be its a preview problem.

Comment: try adding patches on all four sides.

Comment: @DivyaBhalodiya No: the other two sides are (optionally) used to set the 9 patch paddings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging into this, it looks like `CheckBox` itself doesn't support scaling of 9-patch Drawables. The [onDraw()](http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/CompoundButton.java#259) method in `CompoundDrawable` (from which CheckBox is derived), appears to set the drawable bounds from the intrinsic drawable size (as opposed to the setting the bounds from the container size) - which means it doesn't scale.

The background (which is drawn by `View` itself) *does* scale correctly, so you could just set the selector drawable on that.

If however (like me) you wanted a separate background and 'check' drawable, (and you're comfortable with custom views) then you can just subclass `ImageView` and make that `Checkable` instead :

```java
public class StyledCheckBox extends ImageView implements Checkable, View.OnClickListener {
    private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE = { android.R.attr.state_checked };

    private boolean mChecked;

    public StyledCheckBox(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public StyledCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public StyledCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs);

        setFocusable(true);
        setOnClickListener(this);

        // Other constructor stuff...
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        toggle();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        if (mChecked == checked) return;
        mChecked = checked;
        refreshDrawableState();
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }

    @Override
    public int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        if (isChecked()){
            int[] state = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
            mergeDrawableStates(state, CHECKED_STATE);
            return state;
        } else {
            return super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Work with `ImageView` and use `scalyType` `centerCrop`

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/checkbox_cases"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/stepCheckBox1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

This way it will scale up the image to fill the entire space.